Print the first word of a vector on EASY68K
II don't know why its not working, I have  this code, I want to print in a loop the first word of the vector MIXED, and each time the loop goes print the following word.
I have tried making a loop that compares possitions till its a coma ',' beacause it the character that its in between my word, but it does not work.
I have this code :
    ORG $1000
START:
    MOVE.L #MIXED, A0
    MOVE.L #BUFFER, A1  
    
    MOVE.L #14, D0
    MOVE.L #MSG, A1
    TRAP #15
    
    MOVE.B (A0),D0   

LOOP:
    MOVE.B D0,(A1)+
    CMP.B #0,D0
    BEQ FINAL
    CMP.B  #',',(A0)    
    BEQ    PRINT        
    CMP.B  #0,(A0)    
    BEQ    PRINT      
    MOVE.B (A0)+,(A1)+ 
    BRA    LOOP  

PRINT:
    CLR.B  (A1)    
    LEA    BUFFER,A1   
    JSR    PRTSTR    

    MOVE.B #0,(A0)
    MOVE.L #14, D0
    MOVE.L #MIXED,A1
    TRAP #15 
    BRA LOOP

FINAL 
    MOVE.L #11,D0
    MOVE.W #$0101,D1
    TRAP #15
   
    SIMHALT 
    
    ORG $2000
    
MSG DC.B 'The word is:',0
MIXED DC.B 'ATPLANO, NAMZANA, ERSFA, ERCZAE',0
BUFFER DS.B 20

PRTSTR:
    MOVE.B (A1)+,D0 
    BEQ    DONE  
    TRAP   #15  
    BRA    PRTSTR
DONE:
    RTS 
    
    END START


I'm tring to be nice, but this code is almost incomprehencible. Your LOOP is wrong (it's like it is written twice in two different ways and then both piece of code were mixed together and shaken), your PRINT is somewhat wrong (why is it printing MIXED?), your PRTSTR is triple-wrong (placed in DATA so it can't execute, which trap task it executes exactly?, and finally why do you need a function to print a asciiz string here if your code happily print asciiz strings via trap task?)

Hi thank you for answering, I actually have no idea of how could i fixe all of what you said, I'm new to the assembler.  Could yo help me with the code, like I need to eaither print each word one by one of the string or have all of the words on a .txt document wich I should reed but I also have no idea how to make my code reed a .txt document and print the words one by one. Like I have tried with trap and all that but I'm not able.
